# Bitbucket Container SSH Issues

Tags: linux, docker, ssh, alpine-linux

I am running a bitbucket pipeline which needs to SSH to a server.

When the `ssh -i id_rsa user@ip` command runs, it throws:

```
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

And I can see this on the remote server's `/var/log/auth.log` file:

```
Oct 30 12:51:14 i-xxxx sshd[162440]: userauth_pubkey: key type ssh-rsa not in PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms [preauth]
Oct 30 12:51:15 i-xxxx sshd[162440]: userauth_pubkey: key type ssh-rsa not in PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms [preauth]
```

Yet when I try to ssh from the same docker container, with the same private key file from my local machine - everything works as expected and I can see this on the remote machine:

```
Oct 30 12:51:44 i-xxxx sshd[162442]: Accepted publickey for ubuntu from xx.xx.xx.xx port 63823 ssh2: RSA SHA256:<hash>
```

The docker container runs on Linux Alpine and ssh's into an Ubuntu server.

Comment: "Yet when I try to ssh from the same docker container, with the same private key file from my local machine " how does the key get to the bitbucket container?

Comment: Bitbucket allows you to generate ssh keys which will be available on each docker container lunched through the pipeline steps.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by changing the step to use a pre-defined image from atlassian:

```
  - step:
      name: Deploy to Stage
      script:
          - echo "Deploying code"
          - pipe: atlassian/ssh-run:0.2.2
            variables:
              SSH_USER: 'ubuntu'
              SERVER: 'server-ip-here'
              COMMAND: 'code-deployment.sh'
          - echo "Finished Deploying"
```